# Accept webhook POST data to create record using ASP.NET or PHP

Tags: php, asp.net, post, netsuite

We have a lead generation form at Unbounce.com that is capturing lead data. They have a webhook that can transmit the data via POST to any URL that can accept it and process it. We would like to build a page that accepts this data and processes it in NetSuite (probably via the SuiteScript API's, but not sure). http://www.netsuite.com/portal/developers/resources/APIs/Dynamic%20HTML/SuiteScriptAPI/MS_SuiteScriptAPI_WebWorks.1.1.html

Variables To Get From POST
The following variables will be passed from the form in this order to the NetSuite processing page:

```
prog
first_name
last_name
email
parents_email
i_am_a_
phone_number
parents_phone_number
comment
```

Additional Page Variables To Attempt To Grab
Reading the example code below it looks like we can grab and store a few additional items. If so it would be good to store them in the CRM in the visitors profile for future reference:

```
page_id
page_url
variant
```

REQUEST FOR SAMPLE CODE
Since our preferred development enviornment is ASP.NET, can you provide sample code that can accept POST data from a webhook and create a new CRM record within our NetSuite account?

SAMPLE PHP CODE TO GET DATA FROM POST
Example code can be found at http://support.unbounce.com/entries/307685-how-does-the-form-webhook-work

If this were a PHP page you would grab the variables in the following fashion:

```
// This is a sample PHP script that demonstrates accepting a POST from the
// Unbounce form submission webhook, and then sending an email notification.
function stripslashes_deep($value) {
$value = is_array($value) ?
array_map('stripslashes_deep', $value) :
stripslashes($value);
 
return $value;
}
 
// First, grab the form data. Some things to note:
// 1. PHP replaces the '.' in 'data.json' with an underscore.
// 2. Your fields names will appear in the JSON data in all lower-case,
// with underscores for spaces.
// 3. We need to handle the case where PHP's 'magic_quotes_gpc' option
// is enabled and automatically escapes quotation marks.
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
$unescaped_post_data = stripslashes_deep($_POST);
} else {
$unescaped_post_data = $_POST;
}
$form_data = json_decode($unescaped_post_data['data_json']);
 
// If your form data has an 'Email Address' field, here's how you extract it:
$email_address = $form_data->email_address[0];
 
// Grab the remaining page data...
$page_id = $_POST['page_id'];
$page_url = $_POST['page_url'];
$variant = $_POST['variant'];
```

---

However I don't know the code to use to get it into NetSuite. After reviewing the SuiteScript API from NetSuite it looks like we should be using `nlobjRequest` or `nlapiRequestURL`, but I have zero knowledge on how to integrate this with the sample PHP page above.

Comment: @Benj Sicam can you please address the same on my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77388736/netsuite-twilio-outbound-inbound-text-message-service-integration

Answer (score 1):

You would need to create a RESTlet in NetSuite. You can find the documentation on NetSuite's Help Guide. RESTlets are part of NetSuite's SuiteScript API. They are written as JavaScript (of course, using the APIs provided by NetSuite).

When you create a RESTlet, you will be given a URL. Which you should use for your Unbounce web hook. Your RESTlet should parse the JSON data being passed by Unbounce.com.